# Android Studio : install Release App by command line

Tags: android, apk, android-gradle-plugin

I want to export apk file "release apk" from command line
when I run this command  : `gradlew installRelease`

and I found this

> Android Studio Task 'install Release' not found in root project ''.
>   Some candidates are: 'uninstall Release'.

How can I solve it?

Comment: i had same issue as Candidates are: 'installNormalDebug', 'installNormalDebugTest'.MaY I KNOW please how did u solve it as command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there is no such task. You can see all available tasks calling `gradlew tasks`. To assemble release version of `apk` call `gradlew assembleRelease` and then using `adb` install it.

Comment: i did it , but when i use `gradlew install Debug`
and then it stopped on this line : 
`> Building > :app:installDebug`

Comment: @MhmdAljobairi Just stopped without any additional message?

Comment: yes , its stopped without any message
but the comment still show me that its working

Comment: @MhmdAljobairi the problem could be either because of `adb` connection or device/emulator. Try to reboot `adb` server and device.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer for this question:;http://stackoverflow.com/a/33090402/1397160

Answer (score 24):

My experience has been that the `installRelease` task does not become available until you define the `signingConfigs` in the `buildTypes.release` block of your build file, as shown in step 3 of [Signing in Release Mode](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html). Without `signingConfigs`, you will get other release tasks, such as `assembleRelease`, but not `installRelease`.

Answer (score 0):

You may build with Android Studio `Build/Generate Signed APK...`. In this case you'll get `.apk` file in your repository. You then can use `adb install .apk` to install it. You'll have **no** changes in `build.gradle` file in this case.

Alternatively you may change `build.gradle` file as mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#release-mode). In this case you will have `installRelease` task. You may get these changes in `build.gradle` using `Open Module Settings` menu. See details in `Gradle for Android and Java` course from [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/gradle-for-android-and-java--ud867).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the `installRelease` option didn't show up until I deleted the line

```
if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
```