# Uploading proguard mapping file to firebase with adb

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-crash-reporting

> Reference:
>   https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#uploading_proguard_mapping_files_with_gradle

I am able to upload proguard mapping file to firebase using `firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping` task and successfully see the file uploaded but I am unable to directly install the release APK on the device using ADB.

As the `firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping` task only builds the release apk and uploads the mapping file to firebase.

I tried writing a gradle code:

```
  assembleRelease.doLast {
  firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping.execute()
  }
```

It works perfectly fine as it first opens the ADB device selection dialog and then upon device selection, firstly it executes `assembleRelease` task and then `firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping` task but the problem is the `firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping` task already depends on `assemleRelease` task causing `assemleRelease` task to run twice increasing build timings.

I want to run `firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping` task with ADB device without increasing build timings.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is.  If you upload the mappings, you already have built an APK.  Just run a second adb command to install that APK or do whatever you want with it.

Comment: @DougStevenson I want to do it using gradle task. Which I don't know what to code for this to happen.

Comment: I'm saying that if you run the task to upload the mappings, it will also build an APK as part of that process.  Just use that APK, and don't bother running another task.

Comment: @DougStevenson I know it builds the APK but I want that APK to get automatically installed on the device selected connected using ADB.

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with Firebase. If you already have a Gradle task to do that, then put that task on the command line. But I don't think the Android tools provide a task for installing the release apk. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805057/android-studio-install-release-app-by-command-line

Comment: @DougStevenson Yeah I know its nothing to do with Firebase, but as Firebase is providing the gradle task to upload the mapping file. I was hoping if there was a solution to ask for device selection in ADB dialog and then run `firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping` task and then install  & launch app on device.